# Gearman centos issue

Tags: centos, gearman

CENTOS 6.6 x86_64
Gearman v 1.1.8

#### Settings for gearmand

OPTIONS="--listen=0.0.0.0 \
        -q mysql \
        --mysql-host=localhost \
        --mysql-port=xxx \
        --mysql-user=xxx \
        --mysql-password=xxx \
        --mysql-db=xxx \
        --mysql-table=xxx"

I began to notice that creates a queue in the database and is not satisfied.

Check running proccess by:

```
    service gearmand status 
gearmand (pid  6419) is running...
```

Than check error log, it show me that:

```
ERROR 2015-02-09 08:42:40.000000 [  main ] Timeout occured when calling bind() for 0.0.0.0:4730 -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:679
      FATAL 2015-02-09 11:42:29.000000 [  main ] pthread_mutex_lock(Invalid argument) -> libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:685
      ERROR 2015-02-09 15:29:13.000000 [  proc ] GEARMAND_WAKEUP_RUN(Bad file descriptor) -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:382
      FATAL 2015-02-09 15:29:13.000000 [  main ] pthread_mutex_lock(Invalid argument) -> libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:685
      ERROR 2015-02-10 14:35:52.000000 [  proc ] GEARMAND_WAKEUP_RUN(Bad file descriptor) -> libgearman-server/gearmand_thread.cc:382
      FATAL 2015-02-10 14:35:52.000000 [  main ] pthread_mutex_lock(Invalid argument) -> libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:685
      FATAL 2015-02-10 15:21:21.000000 [  main ] pthread_mutex_lock(Invalid argument) -> libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:685
      FATAL 2015-02-11 09:03:29.000000 [  main ] pthread_mutex_lock(Invalid argument) -> libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:685
      FATAL 2015-02-11 13:52:58.000000 [  main ] pthread_mutex_lock(Invalid argument) -> libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:685
      FATAL 2015-02-12 10:30:23.000000 [  main ] pthread_mutex_lock(Invalid argument) -> libgearman-server/gearmand_con.cc:685
```

After restart gearmand all work correctly, and all db queue executed successfuly.
Any help?